A question about Dummit & Foote's explanation on the resolvent cubic and the Galois group
I am at the beginning of my study of field theory and I am reading page $\textbf{615}$ of  $\textbf{Dummit & Foote}$, and the part where I have question about is shown below:

Here for part $\textbf{c1}$, the original polynomial $f(x)$ is any quartic polynomial, $G$ is the Galois group of $f$, $V$ is the Klein 4-group, and $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ are the 3 roots of the resolvent cubic
$$h(x) = x^3 - 2px^2 + (p-4r)x + q^2$$
with
$$\theta_1 = (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)(\alpha_3 + \alpha_4)$$
$$\theta_2 = (\alpha_1 + \alpha_3)(\alpha_2 + \alpha_4)$$
$$\theta_3 = (\alpha_1 + \alpha_4)(\alpha_2 + \alpha_3)$$
where $\alpha_i$s being the roots of $f$.
Now my question is, why we can get $G \subseteq V$ from the fact that $\sigma \in G$ fixes each $\theta_j$, because I didn't see any connection between them. Can somebody give me some hints on this? Thanks!

Consider the following. Let $\sigma \in S_4$ act on the roots $\alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_4$. Then, we can also think about how $\sigma$ acts on the $\theta_i$'s:
$$\sigma(\theta_1) = [\sigma(\alpha_1) + \sigma(\alpha_2)][\sigma(\alpha_3) + \sigma(\alpha_4)]$$
for example. This way, $\sigma$ naturally induces an element of $S_3$ that is acting on the $\theta_i$. Call this mapping $\pi: S_4 \to S_3$.
Now in you case, the subgroup of $S_3$ induced by $G$, that is $\pi(G)$, happens to be trivial, thus you must have $G \subset \ker \pi$.
To determine $\ker \pi$, consider the subgroup $H = \{\sigma \in S_4: \sigma(1)=1\} \subset S_4$. With some more work, we have that $\ker \pi = V$.
From this the red box in c1 follows.

Thanks very much! I am trying to understand what’s going on here.
